# Is there anyway to show dialog to user when noticiation is tapped when app is terminated in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Helle everyone,

I'm using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/example) and firebase cloud messaging to send user notifications. What I'm trying to do is showing user alert dialog when notification on tapped. It works fine when app is on foreground or background. The only problem is  it's not showing the dialog when user on tapped to notification when the app is terminated.

One thing I tried is checking if app launched by notification by using `didNotificationLaunchApp` method of flutter_local_notifications plugin. This attempt failed because result of this method always return false even if I launch the app by tapping on notification.

My question is Is there any other way to do it ? Or what causes `didNotificationLaunchApp` return false all the time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the `ReceivedNotification` class's `notificationTapBackground` method?

Comment: If you're sending notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging. Then why are you using `flutter_local_notifications`? where you can use `firebase_messaging`? Is that because you're using local notifications somewhere other? If yes, which version of `flutter_local_notifications` you're using? because there were some issues before v 6.0.13

Comment: What do you suggest to show notification to  users  other than flutter_local_notification ?

Comment: If you don't want to show local notifications in your app. That is, if you just want to receive notifications from firebase cloud messaging, then you can use `firebase_messaging` plugin itself.